# How to set the parameters of a texture present in the shader editor to the rhythm of music

Tags: animation, texturing, shaders, emission

I wish I could create a texture that comes alive by lighting up and distorting to the rhythm of a song of my choice; for example by connecting parameters relating to the scale, rotations or precisely the emission intensity.
I have already created possible texture animations. Since background music is planned, I wanted to find a way to synchronize the animations in time with the music as if they were low or high pulses.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this the same question as two days ago or something different?

Comment: just change something,  there is something more

Comment: I wrote more precisely and I added some examples, answer me here, so I take that one off

Comment: you look I posted a more detailed question since I need to interact with the parameters present in the texture nodes,to animate the texture and not the object that hosts the texture. . so if you like and you have some advice you can answer in this other question.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the song in the VSE window, create an empty, create a single keyframe (i.e. loc at frame 1), in the graph editor select the keyframe and go to the menu "key - bake sound to f-curves".

Then you can add a driver to any parameter of the shader, pointing to the empty X loc (world related)  and have it following the music, tweaking the values in the dirvers formula.

If you want to separate low frequencies and high, you can create two audio files, one with a low pass EQ (below 160 Hz) and one with an Hi pass EQ (maybe above 2KHz), and repeat the process for every desired EQ band.

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions, and I managed to connect keyframes to the song, but I did not understand how I can control and connect certain keyframes in certain frequencies, or change the audio spectrum, cut it etc. I would like to understand how I can establish where, how and when, how to follow only one specific frequency and ignore the other, and precisely create different levels of frequencies with different pulsations of the texture. Can you show me it with some screenshot ?